# Unable to set environment variables from Google Cloud Run to a Dockerized NextJS app

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, next.js, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I have a NextJS app where I use `.env` files to set environment variables during development. I built a Docker image of the app but I do not include this `.env` file because the values are supposed to be different for each installation so each service on Google Cloud Run will have their own unique set of environment variables which I set from the Cloud Run interface.

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=env source ./.env \
    && npm config set -- //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${GITLAB_TOKEN}
RUN npm config set @scope:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn build

FROM node:18-alpine AS production
WORKDIR /app
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/certificates ./certificates
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/yarn.lock /app/package.json ./
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
USER node
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

However, when I visit the app after it deploys and the environment variables are set from within Cloud Run, the values aren't there. The only way I was able to make it work was to include the `.env` file on the image:

```
COPY --chown=node --from=builder /app/.env ./
```

This makes the image not configurable though as each installation will have the same set of environment variables.

### UPDATE

After more investigation, the problem we're having is **only** for environment variables that have the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix (for frontend use). The environment variables **without** this prefix are accessible from the NextJS backend and `undefined` on the frontend as expected which is good. But the ones with this prefix needs to be accessible from the frontend and it seems like they can only be set during build time. I can't seem to override their values through Cloud Run. This means we have to build a Docker image for each installation we do.

As a context, our NextJS app will be deployed for each of our clients and so we need to define an environment variable called `NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL` because they will all have their own domains. We need to set this environment variable for each client (service) in Cloud Run.

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not run containers under Docker. Not all Dockerfile features are supported. Example: `ENV`, `EXPOSE`, and `PORT` are not supported. Cloud Run will not see the runtime settings in your Dockerfile. Runtime settings are controlled by the CLI or web console GUI. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy This is a good document to read: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried to deploy from the gcloud CLI and used `--update-env-vars` to set the variables. I was able to set the variables since they show up on the Cloud Run interface but when I try to console log them from the NextJS Docker image I built, those environment variables are `undefined`.

Comment: Edit your post to show the current problem. I would need to see the deploy command and the code that accesses the environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've added more info to the question. Let me know if that clears it up better or if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you must distinguish between build and run-time environment variables. The ones in the Dockerfile file are used at build-time, but NodeJS expects the variables from the `.env` file to be set at run-time.

So for CloudRun, you would need to provide environment variables for the runtime when you deploy your image:

```
gcloud run deploy [SERVICE] --image IMAGE_URL --update-env-vars KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2

gcloud run services update SERVICE --update-env-vars KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2
```

For more details on the deployment process check the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting).

**Edit Question NextJs Update:**

Based on the question update, related to all environment variables with the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix, these variables must be set at build-time, since they are compiled into the NextJS code and sent also to the browser. According to [NextJs Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

Comment: I tried to deploy from the gcloud CLI based on your answer and used `--update-env-vars` to set the variables. I was able to set the variables but when I try to console log them from the NextJS Docker image I built, those environment variables are `undefined`.

Comment: @dokgu I've updated the answer was not aware of this NextJs feature, the actual run-time is the client's browser, where you only can use environment variables that were known at build-time.

Comment: So there's no way to set an environment variable at runtime and have it accessible on the frontend?

Comment: @dokgu Depends on the execution model of NextJs, haven't worked with it yet. If there is also a server-side part, this should be able to process also environment variables at runtime (except NEXT_PUBLIC). In general, you would have a frontend and backend part and in the backend, you can use run-time processed environment variables.